# Head First Java-Page 192 (Mixed Messages)

Tags: java

I am attemping an example question from Head First Java:

[image: Question I am attempting]

I typed it as it is on netbeans. Creating 3 classes as classA, classB, classC and Main method as mixed class. In class mixed to I get a error, can some explain me why this happens and how to solve it?

```
        public class classA {
            int ivar =7;
            void m1(){
                System.out.println("A's m1, ");
            }

            void m2(){
                System.out.println("A's m2, "); }

            void m3(){
                System.out.println("A's m3, ");
            }
        }

    public class classB extends classA {
        void m1(){
            System.out.println("B's m1, ");
        }

    }

    public class classC extends classB {
        void m3(){
            System.out.println("C's m3, "+(ivar + 6));}

        }

public class Mixed2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a=new A(); 
//Error Cant find symbol,Symbol:Variable a     location:class mixed 2

       b=new B(); //Same error above and below
        c=new C();
        a2=new C();
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely `class classA` should be `class A` and `a = new A()` should be `A a = new A();`

Comment: If in doubt, copy the code in the question. There is no need to be creative and write something very different as this will only introduce errors when you are learning.

Comment: Not only should you write the same code, I suggest you tryto use the same formatting i.e. spaces, to make the code more readable and easier to check it is the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks a lot for your patience and time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can type it all in one class.
Kindly have a look at the code below.Since you are still learning its best you type it as it is without trying things out differently which can be done later on as you master the language.Happy learning ! .

```
public class mixedsample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        B b=new B();
        C c=new C();
        A a2=new C();

      /*  b.m1();
          c.m2();
          a.m3();
      Answer=B's,m1 ,A's,m2 ,A's,m3*/

     /*  c.m1();
       c.m2();
       c.m3();
A's,m1 ,A's,m2 ,A's,m3 */

     /* a.m1();
     b.m2();
     c.m3();
A's,m1 ,A's,m2 ,A's,m3 */

   /*  a2.m1();
     a2.m2();
     a2.m3();

A's,m1A's,m2 ,A's,m3  */




    }
}

    class A{
        int ivar=7;
        void m1(){
            System.out.println("A's,m1 ");
        }

        void m2(){
            System.out.println("A's,m2 ");

        }

        void m3(){
            System.out.println("A's,m3 ");

        }
    }

    class B extends A {
    void m1(){
            System.out.println("B's,m1 ");

    }
    }
    class C extends B{
    void m1(){
            System.out.println("A's,m1 ");

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `a=new A();` it implies that reference variable `a` has already been declared and you're assigning it now the new 'A' object. To declare a variable you need to give it a type and a name.

```
//you can declare the variable and assign it a reference later like this
A a;
a = new A();

//or you could initialize it all in one line
A a = new A();
```